# How to read JSON file with serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I'd like to read a JSON file and print its contents. I'm trying to use the `serde` crate but can't understand why this does not work:

```
use serde_json;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let path = "./src/input.json";
    let data = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("Unable to read file");
    let res = serde_json::from_str(&data);
    println!("{}", res)
}
```

The error I get is:

```
the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Result<_, serde_json::Error>`
```

How can I read a JSON file? Is there a better way to do this? I could not find a complete example in either the `serde` docs or elsewhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code has two issues. First, you didn't handle the error when parsing JSON. Just like `read_to_string()` returns a `Result` and you had to use `expect()` to get to the underlying value in case everything was fine, the same applies to `serde_json::from_str()`.

Adding the missing `expect()` leads to the second issue, where the compiler complains:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |     let res = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to parse");
  |         ^^^ consider giving `res` a type
```

`serde_json` is strongly typed and can deserialize JSON into Rust types prepared by you. If you want to just inspect untyped JSON, you can use `serde_json::Value` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e1fbec8849f5aadd07e57374c131565d)):

```
use serde_json;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let path = "./src/input.json";
    let data = fs::read_to_string(path).expect("Unable to read file");
    let res: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&data).expect("Unable to parse");
    println!("{}", res)
}
```

You can find this kind of example and more on the [project page](https://github.com/serde-rs/json#operating-on-untyped-json-values).